# Unauthenticate Google OAuth connections

Tags: google-account, google-api, oauth

I authorized access to my account by an application that turned out to not work.  Now I want to remove the authorization in case it was malicious.  How could I do this?

Comment: The direct URL currently is https://myaccount.google.com/permissions

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Go to your [account settings](https://www.google.com/accounts/ManageAccount).
2. Click on `Security` on the left, and then `Edit` next to "Authorizing applications and sites"
3. Revoke the site you wish to remove.

Comment: I went to my account settings, but there was no link like that there.  Clicking the URL you provided directly says that nothing's authenticated.  I guess it must have failed to authenticate too.

Comment: Some things have moved around a bit on the Google account settings page. Now you click Security on the left, then scroll down to "Connected applications and site", and click the Manage Access button.

Comment: correction:
#2 is now under Security > Account permissions > View All

Answer (score 6):

Google keeps changing their interface. As of November 2015, the steps are:

- Go to https://myaccount.google.com
- Click on "Connected apps & sites"
- Click on "Manage apps" to revoke permissions

Comment: Or just go to https://myaccount.google.com/permissions directly